# Does Express Checkout Trigger IPN?

Tags: paypal

I am working on integrating this
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/
Into my website. But my question is while using Express Checkout (posted in link) will it trigger an IPN like normal? Because my website currently just uses a normal PayPal button that when payment is complete my IPN listener receives and processes the IPN message. But I am just wondering if after a payment is made through Express Checkout if IPN message gets sent to my IPN listener like normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Express Checkout triggers an IPN just like any other PayPal transaction, but the txn_type would be different.

If using Express Checkout with a single item the txn_type would be `express_checkout`.  If multiple items are in the Express Checkout payment then it would come through IPN as `cart`.

More details on that available here:  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id08CTB0S055Z